# Spreadsheet Conditional formatting to hightlight duplicate that came in sequence

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Greeting

I'm sorry for the intrusion, but I have a question that seems no one asked before.

I want to know if there is a formula for Conditional Formatting in spreadsheet to highlight certain cell, if a duplicate of certain text came in sequence in the same row.

> ```
>   A                 B     C     D    E    F 
>                     26    27    28   29   30
>  deni               V     X     X    V    X
> ```

In the above example, I want to highlight the name "deni" when there are 2 "X"'s that came in sequence, which was the case at the 27 and 28 date.

Is there any formula for this? I have tried `=OR(B2=C2,C2=D2)` but it only works for 2 cells (B2&C2) with any text (not the "X" only).

Here is an example of the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FDpxgmqhwcqT04AiOLSjMtk_8jR-iaTRbPaJ5UsLdYI/edit?usp=sharing)

PS: i'm sorry, i used excel tag before. but i need this formula to work in google spreadsheet. my bad, sorry

Conclusion: My Question have been answered, i used both formulas from I'-'I and Tom Sharpe and it worked like a charm. Many thanks to the people that responded My Question :)

Comment: Is this an excel question, or a google sheets question?

Comment: it's google sheet question. i'm sorry because the formula sometimes the same with excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:AG2="x")*(E2:AH2="x"))
```

Apply to:

```
A2:A
```

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
=countifs(D2:AG2,"x",E2:AH2,"x")
```

Answer (score 0):

Step1:Select the `range of cells` you want to apply conditional formatting to.

Step2:On the `Home` tab, click `Conditional Formatting`.

Step3:Point to `Highlight Cells Rules`, Go on `More Rules...`

Step4:Choose `Use a formula...` Paste the following one,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(C3:G3,C3:G3)-1)>0
```

[image: Sample]

Step5:Format how you want to `highlight`

Step6:Click `OK` and `Apply`

Hope this helps you.

**Note:** Change the range in the formula as per your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there is a duplicate text (not the "X"), you can use:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(D2:AH2,D2:AH2))>COUNTA(D2:AH2),1,0)
```

`1` means `true`, `0` means `false`. This is because if there is at least one duplicate text, the sum of all the texts' appearance times will greater than the count of all the texts (if not they will be equal).

To be highlight a certain cell, here is `deni`, you can use `Conditional Formatting` -> `Highlight Cell Rules` -> `More Rules` -> `use a formula to datemine which cells to format`, and then paste the formula above in the cell.

[image]